# "&" sign in Magento 2.0 product import is causing errors

Tags: php, csv, import, export, magento2

New to Magento. Very familiar with product import/exports and handling CSV files. Coming from Wordpress/WooCommerce background. Either way, something very strange happens when I upload products via CSV to Magento with & anywhere in the Description or short description. The file says there are errors after upload but no errors listed in log after loaded. But, when I export the products, any item that had the "&" sign (example: Black & White) in the description or short description. It will duplicate the rows. If I get rid of &, just type out the word "and". Alls good. Can you just not use the & symbol at all in Magento 2.0. If I only were working with a couple hundred products no big deal to go in and manually change to written out and. But, I have over 60,000 products working with and this is a real problem.

Last note: use Open Office to work on all CSV files and make sure I save them as UTF-8.

This & thing is driving me nuts and took me a bit to figure out the errors I was having was a result of the &. Any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: `str_replace(' & ', ' and ', $title );`  as far as what Magento allows I can't help you there.  Is there XML involved in it?  I had a hell of a time with quickbooks once with XML and the & ... But that was years ago..  You might want to just double check the & is real a & in UTF-8, such as what MS office does with curly quotes and MDashes, but I am just speculating there.

Comment: Hi Phoenix, Thanks for relpy. Checked to see if it was correct character as a &. It is. It seems to be only with the & sign and will have to deal with it on a base by base issue